# Variadic user defined conversion/constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor, type-conversion

Given the following vector class (meant for 2d, 3d or 4d vector math), that uses std::array, is it possible to define a variadic constructor and/or conversion constructor?

As a follow-up question, is this kind of thing bad practice?  I find myself needing to convert to-from integer, float and double quite a lot.

I know implicit conversions will occur, but my compiler will give me warnings about that (I don't want to switch them off in general).

```
#include <array>

template<typename T0, size_t S>
class Vec
{
public:

    static_assert(S > 1 && S < 5, "vector dimension must be between 2 and 4");
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T0>::value, "type must be arithmetic");

    std::array<T0, S> v;

    Vec() = default;

    template<class T1, class T2>
    Vec(T1 t1, T2 t2) : v({ static_cast<T0>(t1), 
                            static_cast<T0>(t2) }) {}

    template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
    Vec(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3) : v({ static_cast<T0>(t1), 
                                   static_cast<T0>(t2), 
                                   static_cast<T0>(t3) }) {}

    template<class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4>
    Vec(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, T4 t4) : v({ static_cast<T0>(t1), 
                                          static_cast<T0>(t2), 
                                          static_cast<T0>(t3), 
                                          static_cast<T0>(t4) }) {}
};

int main(void)
{
    auto foo1 = Vec<float, 2>(1, 2);
    auto foo2 = Vec<float, 2>(1.0f, 2.0f);
    auto foo3 = Vec<float, 2>(1.0, 2.0);
    auto foo4 = Vec<float, 2>(1u, 2u);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your static assertion regarding template parameter S seems odd. If it has to be greater than 1 and less than 3 then you could just as well say it must be 2.

Comment: Thanks.  Fixed it.  2, 3 or 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is possible.

BTW, in such case you do not need default constructor, as this variadic constructor is even better in a way that it will zero your array...

```
template<typename T0, size_t S>
class Vec
{
public:

    static_assert(S > 1 && S < 3, "vector dimension must be between 2 and 4");
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T0>::value, "type must be arithmetic");

    std::array<T0, S> v;

    template <typename ...T>
    Vec(T&& ...a) : v{{ static_cast<T0>(std::forward<T>(a))...}} 
    {}
};
```

Comment: Oh that's clever.  Thank you.  I think I need an upgrade: "error C2797: 'Vec<float,2>::v': list initialization inside member initializer list or non-static data member initializer is not implemented"

Comment: Note for anyone with VS 2013, this compiles "Vec(T1&& ...a) : v({ static_cast<T0>(a)... }) {}"

Answer (score 2):

If you add an index sequence to the class template:

```
template<typename T0, size_t S, typename = std::make_index_sequence<S>>
class Vec;
```

You can use that extra thing to define both constructors:

```
template<typename T0, size_t S, size_t... Idx>
class Vec<T0, S, std::index_sequence<Idx...>>
{
    template <size_t> using ith_T = T0;

    ...

    Vec(ith_T<Idx>... ts)
    : v({ts...}) // no cast necessary, they're already T0
    { }

    template <typename U,
              typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U, T0>::value>
              >
    Vec(const Vec<U, S>& rhs)
    : v({static_cast<T0>(rhs.v[Idx])...})
    { }

    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

From your example, it looks to me that submitted values have the same type in any case. So, why don't you use a `std::initializer_list`? Moreover, you cast them to the type `T0` before to pass them to the internal `std::array`, so maybe it's worth it. Actually you don't care about the types of the arguments, as far as you can cast them to `T0`.

Comment: They usually have the same type, but sometimes they don't.

Comment: Got it. Was not clear from the example. Anyway, it's a fact that you are not actually interested in their types. Can't you take advantage of this? All the responses you are receiving are exploiting that fact, aren't they?

Comment: It's not the most important thing to be honest.

Comment: Ok. Indeed, either the question is not so clear or I misunderstood it. Sorry. :-)